# How to make iOS and android folders in react native expo project

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on react native expo project and I have no knowledge regarding how to create iOS and android folders within expo project.so please help me regarding how to create iOS and android folders and at last how to make final build. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/#3-eject

> From your project directory, run expo eject. This will download the
>   required dependencies and build native projects under the ios and
>   android directories.